# Regex lookbehind with alterations and whitespace

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to build a Regex in .NET which will match words from a list (using alteration) which does not come after words from another list with space after them.

For example, let's say I'm looking for AAA or BBB, and I want them to not come after WWW or XXX, so that the following should match:

```
DDD AAA
AAA
```

But the following shouldn't:

```
WWW AAA
XXX      BBB
```

I've tried to use the following pattern:

```
(?<!WWW|XXX)(AAA|BBB)
```

But I don't know how to define that there shouldn't be spaces after the first list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, .NET regexes allow indefinite repetion inside lookbehind assertions, so it's uncomplicated to extend this regex:

```
(?<!(?:WWW|XXX)\s*)(AAA|BBB)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!         # Assert it's impossible to match this before the current position:
 (?:WWW|XXX) # WWW or XXX
 \s*         # followed by any number of whitespace characters
)            # End of lookbehind
(AAA|BBB)    # Match AAA or BBB, capture the result in group 1
```

Comment: Wow, fastest answer ever... However, it doesn't seem to work, at least not on RegExr. It doesn't match anything. Could it be there is some problem in the pattern?

Comment: @ml123: This regex only works with a .NET engine. RegExr uses a PCRE engine (I think), and that engine doesn't support the feature I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, I would have never get it by myself, took me a long time to try to solve it.